# joomla integrating external php signup form

Tags: joomla

I have a joomla website.here is the link

[link for site](http://demo.sumofyou.us/crystal-beats/index.php/what-we-offer)I want to integrate a external php signup and login form.I create a php signup form.It works perfecly.
[signup link](http://demo.sumofyou.us/crystal-beats/signup/register-form.php)But the problem is i dont know how to integrate that form to my joomla web pages...I want to secure my web pages..Only registered users can view my page....please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Why have you create your own register form? Joomla already has the one. To see it follow the link `index.php?option=com_user&task=register`, Login for there `index.php?option=com_user&task=login`. If you need more fields to be filled out during registation you may you [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder). This extention allows to add to user profie as many fields as you want

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use Chronoforms to allow for registration that brings in multiple fields as well without having to bring in an external file for registration/login.

Using the tools Joomla has to stay within Joomla is really the best way to go about it.  It will allow you to keep your sanity and keep things as uniformed as possible.